# Average wind direction and speed computation

Tags: trigonometry, average

I am trying to compute the average wind direction and speed based on several data of direction and speed given by my weather station.
I am following this [algorithm](https://www.scadacore.com/2014/12/19/average-wind-direction-and-wind-speed/), however, I don't understand what the author means by the below:

> In this Case the reported North/South Vector is reversed. When you are
> calculating the averages you will have to reverse the radians by *-1.

Any ideas what they mean ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I _think_ I understand. In the picture accompanying that quote in the link, South is marked + and North is marked -. That is the opposite of the usual convention, where the positive y axis extends upward from the origin. So you need to reverse the sign of the N-S component. That's what multiplication by $-1$ does.

Comment: Ok, but when/in which cases would that happen ? `There are some cases where the x/y coordinates are reversed`

Comment: I found at least one gross error on the page: adding $180$ degrees in a place where you should add $360$ degrees. I would recommend finding a better explanation of the necessary algorithms. Absolutely do not follow that page as a cookbook.

Comment: By the way, the entire rest of the page is telling you how to deal with wind data that your receive in the form of direction and speed. So there is no "reported North/South vector." The author seems to be confused. There is no need to worry that you don't understand what the author was saying, because it is simply nonsense.

Comment: It seems to be adding or removing 180 deg based on [that formula](http://www.webmet.com/met_monitoring/622.html) that the author references